# g++ -M -MF options makes output about one object file, how make it to all

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, g++

I use g++ -M -MF options. But this makes output about one object file in my project. How get this output for all .o files in my project?

Comment: Do the same for all source files?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg there are a lot of them. I add this option into IDE settings(in .pro file in QtCreator).

Comment: I don't know how QtCreator and .pro files work, but if you look at other projects using these flags you will see that it's used for every file, one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about QTCreater, but IDEs usually handle header dependencies internally. The GCC options you mentioned are primarily useful if you [write your own Makefile, with its own automatic header dependency handling](http://wiki.osdev.org/Makefile).